# How to take top n categories ordered by date with additional info using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, refactoring

I have model, where properties are

Id, Name, Category, DateCreated, Rating

I have working one decision, but need to rewrite it in a fluent style without from.

```
return await ( from x in _context.Products 
               orderby x.DateCreated 
               group x.Category by x.Category into g 
               orderby g.Count() descending 
               select g.Key
             ).Take(3)
              .Select(element => ((Categories)element).ToString())
              .ToListAsync();
```

Could you help me?

Answer (score 1):

So you have a sequence of `Products`, and you want to make groups of Products. Every group contains Products of one Category. This Category is the Key of the Group.

- You don't want all groups, you only want the 3 Groups that has the most Products.
- You also are not interested what is in the Groups, you are only interested in the string representation of the Category of all Products in the Group.

Whenever you want to make groups of items, but you want something more than just Groups of items, consider to use the [overload of Queryable.GroupBy that has a parameter resultSelector](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.queryable.groupby?view=net-5.0#System_Linq_Queryable_GroupBy__4_System_Linq_IQueryable___0__System_Linq_Expressions_Expression_System_Func___0___1___System_Linq_Expressions_Expression_System_Func___0___2___System_Linq_Expressions_Expression_System_Func___1_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___2____3___)

```
var result = dbContext.Products.GroupBy(product => product.Category,

    // parameter resultSelector: take any found Category, and all Products that have
    // this Category to make one new:
    (category, productsWithThisCategory) => new
    {
        Category = category,
        Count = productsWithThisCategory.Count(),
    })

    // only keep the 3 Groups that has the most Products
    .OrderByDescending(productGroup => productGroup.Count)
    .Take(3)
```

Well, you are not interested in the Count anymore, you only want the string representation of the Category.

```
    .Select(productGroup => productGroup.Category.ToString());
```

IMHO it is not wise to convert your Category to a string. You will probably need more bytes to transfer the data to a local process, and if users of your procedure (= software, not operators) want to interpret the fetched data they have to use relatively slow String comparisons. Besides: if you change a Category, the compiler won't complain, but your code will fail.

So consider to return the Category as the type it really is (enum?). Only convert to strings when you need to convert it to readable text (for operators, text files, etc)

```
.Select(productGroup => productGroup.Category);
```